# How to bypass a 'cookiewall' when using scrapy?

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

I'm a new user to Scrapy. After following the tutorials for extracting data from websites, I am trying to accomplish something similar on forums.

What I want is to extract all posts on a forum page (to start with). However, this particular forum has a 'cookie wall'. So when I want to extract from http://forum.fok.nl/topic/2413069, each session I first need to click the "Yes, I accept cookies"-button.

My very basic scraper currently looks like this:

```
class FokSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'fok'
allowed_domains = ['forum.fok.nl']
start_urls = ['http://forum.fok.nl/']

def parse(self,response):
    divs = response.xpath("//div").extract()
    yield {'divs': divs}
    pass
```

The divs I get are not from the actual forum thread, but from the cookie wall.

Here's the html of the button:

```
<a href="javascript:acceptCookies()" class="button acc CookiesOK" onclick="document.forms['cookies'].submit();acceptCookies();">Ja, Ik wil een goed werkende site...<span class="smaller">...en accepteer de cookies</span></a>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to bypass this cookiewall (artificially 'click' the button) and go to the actual webpage I'm trying to scrape? (Even the right Google search terms/documentation pages etc would be very helpful)

Comment: `extract` needs `()` to run it.

Comment: if page use `JavaScript` then you may need `Selenium` to control web brawser which will load page and run `JavaScript`. Or you have to analyze JavaScript's code and find out what urls it uses and do the same with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found multiple ways to solve this problem:

- Simply having adding `/?token=77c1f767bc31859fee1ffe041343fa48&allowcookies=ACCEPTEER+ALLE+COOKIES` to the start url worked for this specific case
- I later switched to a `CrawlSpider` instead of a normal Spider, then I could add the xpath of the cookie button as the first [rule](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules).
- Clicking the button using the earlier mentioned `Selenium` also worked, but is a lot of hassle that is not really necessary...

Comment: Hi Teresa, could you paste the actual code you used? That could help out future readers like me ;)