# How to scrape page behind "cookie wall" with Scrapy

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

Using scrapy I want to scrape this page:

https://tweakers.net/categorie/496/laptops/producten/

The first time you visit the page it doesn't show the list of products that's normally found on that URL. Instead, it shows another page, which asks the user to accept the website's cookies.

How do I get past this initial page using Scrapy?

I have found this SO question, and answer, which sounds good, but my understanding is too limited to know which steps to take next to fix the problem. [How to bypass a 'cookiewall' when using scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651881/how-to-bypass-a-cookiewall-when-using-scrapy)

Here's the html of that first page, on which the user is asked to allow the website's cookies:

```
<!doctype html><!-- © 1998 - 2019 de Persgroep Online Services B.V. -->
            <html lang="NL">
            <head>
                <title>Tweakers</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tweakimg.net/x/styles/framework/main.css?1548760374">
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                        background: #4c4c4c url(https://tweakimg.net/g/cookies/bg.jpg) repeat-x;
                        min-width: 0;
                    }
                    #cookieContainer {
                        background: url(https://tweakimg.net/g/cookies/backdrop.jpg) no-repeat center top;
                        height: 1438px;
                        padding-top: 100px;
                    }
                    #cookieOverlay {
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        padding: 15px;
                        max-width: 460px;
                        background: #f9fafa;
                        border-radius: 2px;
                        line-height: 1.6;
                    }
                    #cookieOverlay ul {
                        padding-left: 18px;
                    }
                    #cookieOverlay img {
                        float: left;
                        margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
                    }
                    #cookieOverlay h1 {
                        margin: 10px 0;
                    }
                    #cookieOverlay p {
                        clear: both;
                    }
                    #cookieOverlay button {
                        margin-right: 5px;
                    }

                    @media (max-width: 767px),(max-device-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait),(max-device-width: 499px) and (orientation: landscape) {
                        #cookieContainer {
                            padding-top: 0;
                        }
                    }
                </style>
                <script src="https://tweakimg.net/x/scripts/min/general.js?1549274572"></script>
                <script>
                    loadJS(
    'https://config-prod.choice.faktor.io/ec4dd53f-5731-40af-909f-c609b1960e3b/faktor.js',
    function(res)
    {
        if (res == 'loaded' && window.__cmp)
        {
            __cmp('acceptAll', function(data){});
        }
    }
);


                    function formSubmitActions(form)
                    {
                        // Log consent for IAB CMP framework
                        window.__cmp && __cmp('acceptAll');

                        return true;
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="cookieContainer">
                    <div id="cookieOverlay">
                        <img src="https://tweakimg.net/g/cookies/logo-50x50.png" width=50 height=50 alt="Tweakers logo">
                        <h1>Cookies op Tweakers</h1>
                        <br>
                        <h3>Tweakers maakt gebruik van cookies</h3>
                        <p>
                            Tweakers gebruikt cookies, JavaScript en vergelijkbare technologie onder andere om u een optimale gebruikerservaring te bieden. Ook kunnen we hierdoor het gedrag van bezoekers vastleggen en analyseren, en deze informatie toevoegen aan bezoekersprofielen.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Cookies kunnen worden gebruikt om op Tweakers advertenties te tonen en artikelen aan te bevelen die aansluiten bij uw interesses. Ook derden kunnen uw internetgedrag volgen, zoals bijvoorbeeld het geval is bij embedded video's van YouTube.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Cookies kunnen ook worden gebruikt om op sites van derden relevante advertenties te tonen. Dankzij cookies van derde partijen kunt u daarnaast informatie delen via sociale media, zoals Twitter en Facebook. Meer informatie hierover vindt u op <a href="https://tweakers.net/info/algemene-voorwaarden/cookies/">tweakers.net/cookies</a>.                           
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Om pagina's op Tweakers te kunnen bekijken, moet u de cookies accepteren door op 'Ja, ik accepteer cookies' te klikken.
                        </p>

            <form id="cookieAcceptForm" method="post" action="https://tweakers.net/my.tnet/cookies/" onsubmit="return formSubmitActions(this)">
                <span class="nowrap"> <button class="fancyButton" name="decision" value="accept" type="submit" title="Ja, ik accepteer cookies">Ja, ik accepteer cookies</button></span>
                <input type="hidden" name="returnTo" value="MjM2MzkxODQwNTI4YmU0NGNlMGI4NTlmZTQyYmUxOTI1NzZlMDRiNg|https://tweakers.net/categorie/496/laptops/producten/">
                <input type="hidden" name="fragment" value="">

                <input type="hidden" name="tweakers_token" value="7WmTnuoWXGheXOWZPxKqdHyXLfI0utxNhXbI1HxJ">
            </form>
            <script>document.forms['cookieAcceptForm'].elements['fragment'].value=location.hash;</script>
                        <br>
                        <p>Klik <a href="https://tweakers.net/my.tnet/login/?location=https%3A//tweakers.net/categorie/496/laptops/producten/">hier</a> om in te loggen.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>window.scrollTo(0,0);</script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: can you check the code of my crawlspider in [my github](https://github.com/yackoa/yet_another_crawler/blob/master/crawler/spiders/crawler.py) and then try whats mentioned in the link you posted. specifically `add the xpath of the cookie button as the first rule. `

Comment: Thanks, I am goin to look into xpath. See how that works.

Comment: sure. let me know if it solves the issue, so that I can update the answer here :)